# Regulate Vent With Relay and Transformer

Tags: relay

I have a vent (inductive load) and a SPDT relay.

Currently, I'm directing the power into COM and out of NO. This gives me two options 0,100%. Now I want to buy a transformer and wire it to NC. My goal is to run the vent at 50% if the relay is in the default position and at 100% when the relay is switched. The relay may not switch reliable (no motor relay/ solid state, http://www.chineserelay.com/Public/Uploads/file/29701358739272.pdf).

Is this possible or can anything happen to the vent?

EDIT:

Maybe this circuit diagram helps (I'm not sure if it is drawn correct, I also did not find the matching parts but it's about the wiring itself):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flko9Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Are you sure your vent works that way and isn't a simple open/close device? I would be more inclined to look for a mechanical way of manipulating the vent's default state.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. What do you expect to happen in the vent?

Comment: The transformer cuts the power to the half, the vent can be dimmed like that. I want to run it 100% (when the state of the relay is NO) and 50% when the state is NC. The transformer will be between the NC output and the fan.

Comment: A vent is not the same thing as a vent fan.  It still won't work like you expect, though.  AC motor speed isn't usually controlled by voltage.

Comment: Test your idea with just the transformer an the vent fan and see if you can reliably run the fan at a lower speed that way.  If that works, then you can worry about switching speeds with the relay.

Comment: Maybe I'm using the wrong english words. It's a pipe fan, eg.
http://www.onestopgrowshop.co.uk/fans-filters-and-air-control/duct-fans/systemair-rvk-sileo-150e2-a1-6-inch-150mm-in-line-duct-fan-428m3-hr.html
I tried it, both 50% and 100% work.

Comment: Good.  You need to clarify your question a bit.  You are controlling the speed of a fan by switching the supply voltage and you need help figuring out how to wire it.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there are a few "burn your house down" type problems with this.

### That won't work as a motor control

AC induction motors don't go half-speed when you reduce voltage, they just malfunction and overheat. To control an induction motor, you change the frequency, e.g. with a variable frequency drive.

If it's a vent *fan*, your better play is to have two smaller ones and shut one off, doing an end-run around the whole motor-control issue.  Controlling AC motors is hard.

If this is a motorized vent, you really need to review the documentation on the vent regarding how to control its position.  This may lend itself to control via position detection.

### Other than that, Mrs. Lincoln, bucking is reasonable

Reducing voltage won't work here, but *bucking* as a concept is an acceptable way to reduce voltage.  That's placing the secondary of a transformer in series with the load, in-phase (to boost) or counter-phase (to buck) final voltage. That would work, say, on a *heater*, but not on a motor (depending on motor type).

That's not what your schematic shows; the schematic is a mess because it shows the switch shorting one winding of the transformer.  Look up how bucking is normally done.

### Anything mains voltage needs to be listed

Mains electrical is an entirely different craft with different rules. Anything you hook to mains voltage needs to be listed *in a different way* than electronic components: it needs to be listed as an assembly, and provided in a package that's appropriate for installation.  The best way to get appropriate parts is from an *electrical supply* (the people with rolls of twin-and-earth [12/2 in USA], conduit, hangers, fishing tape) or a *heating and cooling* shop (the people with furnaces and air conditioners).

[no](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/100) 
[image]
[yes](http://www.functionaldevices.com/building-automation/display.php?model=RIB12P)
[image]

They might be the same relay internally, the difference is the second one is designed to mount on a USA-style junction box, and the whole assembly has been listed in a testing lab to meet mains standards.   The first relay, if listed, means it is allowable in an assembly which is then certified as an assembly.

If your electrical inspector finds the first one, he'll make you rip it out; the second one will pass inspection.  Check your nation's electrical code; if it's the United States, start at NEC 110.

What you do on the low voltage DC side, on the other hand, is far less regulated.  So generally you want your low voltage gear controlling a listed relay like this.

Comment: Thx for the long reply. The transformer is used for that, it is sold on sites which also sell fans and sell the transformer to control them. E.g. this is a similar one: https://www.distrelec.de/en/one-phase-fan-transformers-sba-trafotech-elt-230-80-230vac-5a/p/15600905. For the relays I'm using this controller (which has the above relay on the pcb): https://shop.controleverything.com/collections/relay-controller/products/8-channel-relay-controller-i2c?variant=25687945547

Comment: The fact of it being sold online is meaningless. Question is whether *that* fan is engineered to work with *that* transformer, and *listed* as such (by a testing agency such as TUV or CSA). Most of the civilized world requires using only listed equipment in mains electrical, and requires obeying the labeling and instructions provided.  So there would be instructions saying how to use the transformer.  The item in the second link is a component, fine in the low-voltage side.

Comment: The difficulty I have is that I have a test fan for my prototype but I won't know which exact fan (only the category/type) may be used in the end. But it doesn't seem like an exception that a fan can be controlled with a transformer, e.g. http://www.ventilation-system.com/cat/rsa5e-m/ can you give me some information why this is not working? And asked diff. let's assume I can switch the fan with the relay and I can control it with the transformer is there any danger in combining both?

Comment: The fan motor has to be built to match the type of speed controller driving it.  From the brochures it appears certain of that company's motors are listed to work with certain of their speed controls, e.g. Their lo/hi wired motors that seem to work with either a lo/hi switch, or a smart controller that gives more speeds.  If your builder plans to give you any random fan and motor, that could be a problem.